# Understanding NSDate difference between hours

Tags: ios, nsdate

If i check the date now i get (at 20:05 in the evening)

```
2015-07-14 17:05:41 +0000
```

So where are the 3 hours difference gone ? i guess its a zone thing.

My basic question is, can i leave it like that assuming he will add the same hours when i set alarm notification with this date  ?

E.g if i set alarm at real time- `20:05` , for a date that shows `17:05` , will it be in that same hour of the day- means 20:05 ?? or is it wrong to work like that?

Comment: Look at the output - it is showing you that the time is in the `+0000` timezone. It appears you live in the `+0300` timezone.

Comment: [point in time vs. its representation at specific location](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29427932/457406)

Answer (score 0):

Twice a year people complain about alarms going off at the wrong time when daylight savings time starts or end.

NSDate logs the date in UTC, which is almost but not quite exactly the same as GMT, which is Greenwich Mean Time (British summertime). If we both look at our watches right now, we will see different times, but NSDate will report the same time all over the world.

If someone wants to set an alarm for 20:05 tomorrow then you need the functionality in NSCalendar to find out what NSDate to set. On 363 days of the year, 20:05 tomorrow is exactly 24 hours or 86,400 seconds after 20:05 today. On two days of the year, it isn't.

Of course if I set an alarm for 20:05 tomorrow and then take a flight from London to New York, you can only guess whether I wanted an alarm at 20:05 London or New York time.