# How to get the current time instead of device time in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

Im using `[NSDate date]`  to get the current time.
Everything works fine if user don't change the time...I mean if user changed manually instead of setting it automatically. 
Then how can I get the original time?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't trust the device time, you'll need to call out to an external service using NTP

Comment: Is there is no possibility instead of NTP service.If suppose I'm in offline and changed the date, and after some time  set the date to automatically. Then How Apple is getting original time in offline also..

Comment: So iOS devices can synchronize time when offline? In that case Apple might use the time stamp that is part of the GPS signal. Or they use the time stamps that cellular base stations broadcast. Neither are available for you.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch  I stopped my locations services, and there is no sim in my iPhone but still getting time, How its possible for apple ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't find this out. The only way that goes through my mind is to take date from your server.. :(

Comment: If the server is in different timezone how to convert those based on user time zone.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406819/how-to-convert-server-response-date-to-local-timezone basically you keep date in UTC and when get it from server you add local timezone when creating the NSDate

Comment: Hope that is only way, Can't v get time from Apple servers

Comment: I think There should be any global  Service To get original UTC time instead of getting  our server time

Comment: It should be. but from what i searched i haven't find any posible sollution to server.

Comment: k I too searching some thing like this, but didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];                               
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

   NSString *startTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDateTime];                   

   NSString *endTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endDateTime];

   NSLog(@"User's current time %@ and end Time %@ in their preference format",startTime,endTime);
```